# Shift a character forward by three spaces in C

Tags: c, string

Write a function that, using the strrot function,
modifies each string of the given array s out of n strings.
The function prototype is:

```
void rot_all(char *s[], int n);
```

Here's my code I only don't know how to do the last function.

```
char rot3(char c) // Function shifts a letter by three spaces (eg 'a' -> 'd')
{
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') return c += 3;
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') return c += 3;
    return c;
}


void strrot(char *str)
{
    int d = strlen (str);
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        str[i] = rot3(str[i]);
    }
}

void rot_all(char *s[], int n)
{
    
}

int main ()
{
    char str[23];
    scanf("%s",str);
    strrot(str);
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't give us your assignment.  Ask one question.  The problem with `rot3()` is that you don't do the rotation.  If letter is 'z' rotating it isn't 'z' + 3 but 'c'.

Comment: What's so difficult about implementing `rot_all`? It's almost identical to `strrot`. You have a length, you use a loop, and you call a function. Regarding the `rot3` function as the comment above mentions, you need your rotation to be circular. Subtract the first letter in the range, and do the arithmetic modulo 26 before shifting back. _e.g_ `c = 'a' + (c - 'a' + 3) % 26;`

Comment: `c - 'A'` is a useful calculation.  That takes the ASCII code of the character and subtracts the ASCII code for A.  This will turn the alphabet A, B, C, ..., Z into numbers:  0, 1, 2, ..., 25.  Similarly, `c - 'a'` helps if the letter is lower case.  `(n + 3) % 26` is another useful calculation.  It turns the sequence: [0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 22, 23, 24, 25] into [3, 4, 5, 6, ..., 25, 0, 1, 2].  Similarly `(n + 26 - 3) % 26` is useful for transforming back.  `'A' + n` will turn [0, 1, 2, ...] into ['A', 'B', 'C', ...]

Answer (score 1):

The assumption is that `c` is a either lower or upper case letter.  Using an `assert()` to document this.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char rot3(char c) {
    assert(isalpha(c));
    char offset = isupper(c) ? 'A' : 'a';
    return offset + (c - offset + 3) % ('Z' - 'A' + 1);
}

void strrot(char *str) {
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        str[i] = rot3(str[i]);
    }
}

void rot_all(char *s[], int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        strrot(s[i]);
    }
}

int main () {
    char *strs[] = {
        strdup("Hello"),
        strdup("World")
    };
    rot_all(strs, sizeof(strs) / sizeof(*strs));
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(strs) / sizeof(*strs); i++) {
        printf("%s\n", strs[i]);
        free(strs[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is:

```
Khoor
Zruog
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) { str[i] = rot3(str[i]); }` makes for slow code re-computing the length as `str` in changed. Consider `for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) { ...}`.

Comment: Done. Won't clang/gcc treat it as a loop constant?

Comment: Note that `str[]` is changing, not constant.  Consider `ot3(str[i]);` may return a zero - do you expect the compiler to analyze `ot3()` and somehow know it does not?  Since `str[i] = 0;` appears possible, `strlen(str)` needs to be recomputed each iteration.

Comment: Given alternate locales, are even you certain `ot3()` cannot return a 0?

Comment: I am certain of fewer and fewer things with age :-)

Comment: That only means you are wiser.